# PushNotificationIOS.presentLocalNotification() doesn't work in react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use `PushNotificationIOS` in react-native, but nothing happens.

I have the following code:

```
PushNotificationIOS.requestPermissions();

PushNotificationIOS.presentLocalNotification(
  {
    alertBody: 'Hello world!!!'
  }
);
```

I'm running on a device and I did enable notifications for my app.

Moreover, when I run

```
PushNotificationIOS.checkPermissions((permissions) => {
  console.log(permissions);
});
```

It returns me

```
{ badge: 1, sound: 1, alert: 1 }
```

Indicating that the notifications have indeed been enabled.

However, I still cannot see anything on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I was trying to display a push notifications while still having the app in the foreground. Of course, that wouldn't work. An app has to be in the background for a push notification to work.

Comment: Thank you, I was making the same mistake. I would never have guessed since notifications work fine in Android even with the app in the foreground (with the react-native-push-notification module).

Comment: Well guys, come on, are you using your phones!? Of course you can have notifications while the app is foreground! Given you have a chat app, you're looking at a conversation and get a response in another conversation. Believe it or not but you got a notification that you can EVEN touch to switch conversation. Please un-accept this answer, it is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how can get in-app notifications while you are using it?